# Retrieving a bytes object of length 1 from another bytes object

Tags: python, byte, python-3.4

Taking the following example:

```
>>> bytes_obj = "FooBar".encode()
```

Attempting to retrieve the first item from the `bytes` iterable returns an `int`:

```
>>> type(bytes_obj[0])
<class 'int'>
```

How is it possible to instead retrieve another `bytes` object of length 1 yielding something equal or similar to what is produced using `bytes((bytes_obj[0],))`, which is anything but elegant or succinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *slice* `bytes` to get another `bytes` object:

```
>>> bytes_obj = "FooBar".encode()
>>> type(bytes_obj[:1])
<class 'bytes'>
>>> bytes_obj[:1]
b'F'
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that slice notation for an object could yield such contrasting results to simple indexing. Thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminCrawford: just like with other sequences like tuples and lists; indexing gives the contents, slicing a new object of the same type. Strings just happen to have their contents be strings too, but they are the exception.